# Bash : Find parent process id of a script from another script and take some actions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, process

I have a script workingScript.sh .I have another script called as monitorscript.sh which I want to use to monitor the processid activities of the workingScript.sh.

I want to ensure that if there is any **wc/cat** process id created apart from the ones generated from 17506(parent process of workingScript.sh),it should be killed by  monitorscript.sh

```
ps aux|grep "workingScript*"
svc.test+ 25896  0.0  0.0 112812   984 pts/3    S+   01:15   0:00 grep --color=auto workingScript*
svc.test+ 17506  0.0  0.0 113288  1072 ?        S    Mar18   0:00 sh workingScript.sh
svc.test+ 17510  0.0  0.0 113412   868 ?        S    Mar18   0:03 sh workingScript.sh
```

The process tree for workingScript.sh parent process id shows like this.

```
pstree -p 17506
    sh(17506)─┬─cat(17509)
      └─sh(17510)─wc(17569)
```

So at any point of time, if any wc/cat process id gets started apart from the ones created by workingScript.sh(in this case 17509/17569 as per above process tree) it should be killed

We can use **PPID** to get processid of same script but how can we get for different script and related child processes for a different script

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Echo the PPID of the "different script" to a file from within the script. You can then reference the file and the PID from another process.

Comment: Overall, `it should be killed by monitorscript.sh` this is just wrong approach. I do not really follow what's the point - if `cat` is short enough, that `monitorscript.sh` is not even going to notice it. `how can we get for different script and related child processes for a different script` As you showed, `ps aux | grep` written better as `pgrep` and `pstree`. You used them in your post - so use them in your script.

Comment: @kamilCuk Actually for demonstration i have mentioned cat ,catually its inotifywait process which i want to kill.So i agree with your point that why someone would try to kill a cat process but actually its not like that

Answer (score 0):

Run the `workingScript.sh` with `LD_PRELOAD` with overridden `exec*()` calls. Then inside these `exec*()` calls check if the command resolves to `wc` or `cat` executable. If it is, `raise` some killing signal if you want. Remember to export `LD_PRELOAD` so that child processes `exec*()`s are also overridden.

---

If you wish to *periodically* check the script for processes, then just find the pid and kill them:

```
pid=$(pgrep workingScript.sh)
while sleep "$polling_period"; then
   # ex. killing cat
   pkill -P "$pid" cat
fi
```

Comment: pid=$(pgrep workingScript.sh) this doesnt give any output ..Is it because I have to run the workingScript.sh with LD_PRELOAD with overridden exec*() calls. Any solution without this LD_PRELOAD?

Comment: `Is it because I have to run` No, it's most probably because the matching expression is wrong. Check the name of the process and match against it properly. `Any solution without this LD_PRELOAD?` You can attach a debugger or run `strace -ff` (or `ptrace()`) on the process to get exec calls.